# whitelisting params that are not in the model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, whitelist

I am trying to pass some extra attributes that are not a part of the model attributes.

```
 def fulfillment_params
    params.require(:fulfillment).permit(
      :id, :ids, :batch_edit_fulfillment_ids, 
        :remarks,
    )
  end
```

How am I supposed to do this correctly? `batch_edit_fulfillment_ids` is a field I am using in one of my forms, but when I try to do an `update(fulfillment_params)` action, rails assumes that this is one of the fields in my model and throws an error that there is no such field in the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to pass it to `fulfillment_params`.
Use just `params[:fulfillment][:batch_edit_fulfillment_ids]`.

Comment: so you mean I don't need to include these parameters in the whitelist?

Comment: Yes, you can if it's value is a string or array. It's dangerous only when value is a hash.
Can you say what you do with this value?

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
def fulfillment_params
  hash = {}
  hash.merge! params.require(:fulfillment).slice(:id, :ids, :remarks) # model attributes
  hash.merge! params.slice(:batch_edit_fulfillment_ids) # non-model attributes
  hash
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If `batch_edit_fulfillment_ids` is not a field in table then you definitely not going to update it. It doesnot make sense. So you do not need to add it in the `whitelist` because you whitelist only those `attributes` that are acceptible to be updated by users.

For more info see this : https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/10/02/rails-strong-params-whilisting-params-implementation-details/

In you case you can refer to Alex's answer or if you want to access the value in the model then you can set it

```
class Fulfillment < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessor :batch_edit_fulfillment_ids
end
# in controller you can set
@fulfillment.batch_edit_fulfillment_ids = params[:fulfillment][:batch_edit_fulfillment_ids]
```